# Can i set price programmatically of my android app on Google play?

Tags: android, google-play

how can i set price value programmatically of my android app . Basically i want to pass price value for google play to set price my app.

Comment: Why? So user can decide what to pay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that that is possible to set the price of your app out side of the dev console , it is my understanding that the only way to set the price for your app is in the developer console.

Comment: means no chance to pass value from app to google play store(set price value for my app)

Comment: Yes, you will have to do it in the developer console - http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/console.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API to change your developer console settings.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. And not advisable; go through Google first. Sounds a bit fishy.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement in-app purchase.

Then have two in-app products one at the full price and one at the lower. Then when they enter the correct code, you let them see the lower priced product.

Comment: hi Weston, i have success fully connect with google play after click on button but its not showing price and card number.